# set -e ignored in subshell when followed by conditional control operator

Tags: bash, conditional-statements, subshell

I can't find any documentation indicating that this is correct behavior.  I've verified this behavior on bash 4.2.25 and 4.1.2.  Those are the latest to which I have simple access.
Much appreciated if anybody has an explanation for why the conditional changes the behavior of the preceding subshell.

```
# ( set -e; false ; echo bye )
# ( set -e; false ; echo bye ) || echo "failed"
bye
#
```

thanks,
Brian

Comment: Is this a kinda-sorta perversion of: "The shell
                      does not exit if the command that fails is part of the command list immediately following a while or until keyword, part of the test following the if or elif reserved words, part of any command executed in a && or ││ list except the command following the final  &&  or
                      ││,  any command in a pipeline but the last, or if the command’s return value is being inverted with !."

Comment: See my answer; that was my thinking as well. Incidentally, the same behavior exists in the forthcoming 4.3 version as well.

Comment: same behavior in a recent ksh too.

Comment: Somebody here pointed me to this: http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=537

Comment: Sounds like it will be too difficult to fix and was rejected.  Personally, I think it's fine to skip a set -e in a {} context, since there's no guaranteed subshell... but () gives me a false sense of protection from the external shell in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the the following [link](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=52)

> The -e setting shall be ignored when executing the compound
>             list following the while, until, if, or elif reserved word,
>             a pipeline beginning with the ! reserved word, or any
>             command of an AND-OR list other than the last.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the emphasized portion of the description of the `-e` option in the `bash` 4.2 man page applies:

> The shell does  not  exit  if
>                         the  command  that fails is [...] **part** of any command executed  in
>                         a  &&  or || list [...]

The `false` command is part of the subshell which makes up the LHS of the `||` operator, so although it fails, the `-e` is ignored. Arguably, this is a bug, since `false` is not part of an `||` in the shell where `set -e` is actually set.